# Why is my console.log logging undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to console log the value of "this" which is my dynamically created div. I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong, as my variable returns the correct thing.

```
getGames().done(function(results){
        $.each(results, function (i, gameData){
            $.each(gameData, function(key, game){

                var gamesHome = game.home_team_conference;
                var gamesAway = game.away_team_conference;


                if(gamesHome == "Big West" || gamesAway == "Big West"){
                    // console.log(this);
                    var gameId = game.id;
                    var homeTeam = game.home_team;
                    var awayTeam = game.away_team;
                    var pointTotal = game.total_points_bet;
                    var gameTime = game.game_time_hour;
                    var gameDate = game.game_time_date;
                    var gameId = game.id;
                    var network = game.broadcast_network;
                    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
                    var hueTwo = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';


                $('.wrapper').append('\
                    <div class="main-wrapper col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">\
                    <div class="game-cards">\
                    <div class="chart-container">\
                    <canvas id="'+ homeTeam +'" width="500" height="500"></canvas>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="right-info">\
                    <h4>' + awayTeam + '<br>' + " @ " + '<br>' + homeTeam +'</h4>\
                    <h5 id="time-channel">'+ gameDate +' @ ' + gameTime  + '<br>' + ' On ' + network +'</h5>\
                    <div class="total-points-live">\
                    <h5>Total Points Bet</h5>\
                    <h5 id="point-total">'+ pointTotal +'</h5>\
                    <p>'+ awayTeam +'</p>\
                    <input class="bet-input" data-team-type="'+ awayTeam +'" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmount" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                    <p>'+ homeTeam +'</p>\
                    <input class="bet-input" data-team-type="'+ homeTeam +'" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmount" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                    <p class="bet-button">Click To Place Bet</p>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    ');

                    $('.bet-button').click(function(){
                        console.log($(this).homeTeam)
                    })
```

So on the click of .bet-button I want to return that divs specific homeTeam, but my console is logging it as "undefined". I can console.log it as just homeTeam and it will give me the values for more than one. So I'm not exactly sure what's going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because `$(this)` is the `$('.bet-button')` DOM node and does not have a property `homeTeam`.

Comment: Ah so what would be a good way of getting the value that I'm wanting?

Comment: you can use ` let self = this;` and use `self` instead of ` this`

Comment: Sure thing :) You can't access a JavaScript variable from a DOM node. Instead, where you define `<p>homeTeam</p>`, you'll want to give that element a unique class or ID, and then use jQuery's `find()` method to find it in the actual DOM :)

Comment: So could I do var self = $(this); 

and then do self.homeTeam?